# how to insert multiple size of app icon for electron app using electron builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electronic-signature

I'm making an electron app and there is only one option to choose it 256by256 and when the app is packaged the app icon is very poor on resolution i want  to select multiple like 16by16 64by64 and other for electron using electron builder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.